# django how to use variable in query filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a Django filter using a variable as filter input for a contains query on a jsonfield. I just cannot get it to work. Form what I'm finding the solution should be using kwargs but I'm lost how to implement this.

```
lookupValue = "[{{\"displayName\":\"{0}\"}}]".format(user['name'])
print("value is: ")
print(lookupValue)
recent_user_calls = CallRecord.objects.filter(participants__contains = [{"displayName":"Some Name"}])
#recent_user_calls = CallRecord.objects.filter(participants__contains = lookupValue)
```

I create the value I want to search and put it in lookup value. In the last commented out line I try to use this value in de query. This does not work as where the previous line works perfectly. A few lines before I print the lookupvalue and it is 100% the same as the fully typed out version. I'm have been staring at this for 2 days. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the variable you are passing in the query is a string and not a list.

You can write:

```py
recent_user_calls = CallRecord.objects.filter(participants__contains = [{"displayName":user['name']}])
```

Or you can directly filter using the key:

```py
recent_user_calls = CallRecord.objects.filter(participants__displayName=user['name'])
```